# Notifications permission pop-up will always appear in flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying for days to get rid of Notifications Permission pop-up that appears in my Flutter app on first app run.

My code is the following:

```
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    check_internet_connection();
    super.initState();
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'Myapp',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Text('test')
      );
    }
}
```

In general, I am using firebase and firebase messaging in my app.
While trying to disable the permission request, I wanted to see what causes the appearance of the pop-up window, hence I deleted almost everything (trial & error) from my main, leaving just the code above.
I am still getting the notifications permissions request on my iOS real device.

In my pubspec.yaml I have this: firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0

How can I disable the pop-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found why I have this behaviour.
It is because of my AppDelegate.swift file where I have added this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
  options: authOptions,
  completionHandler: { _, _ in }
)

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

By removing the requestAuthorization() I don't get the pop-up anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Faz answer helped me!! Additionally if you are using flutter_local_notifications plugin then you have to explicitly set it up to not to ask for permission by following way

```dart
final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
      DarwinInitializationSettings(
    requestSoundPermission: false,
    requestBadgePermission: false,
    requestAlertPermission: false,
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
  );
```

For more information, please see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694451/flutter-block-push-notification-permission-on-ios-at-startup) and [this issue](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1314) along with [this part of the readme](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications#ios-all-supported-versions-and-macos-1014-requesting-notification-permissions).

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to Flutter Badges. I was clearing firebase notification badges during app startup which in turn was requesting access to notifications

https://pub.dev/packages/badges